# Share Expo App without Apple Developer Account

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

I am currently developing an A React Native App with Expo and would like to share it with other people so that they can use it on their iPhone. However, I need a paid Apple Developer Account to build it for iOS, which I dont have, as I dont want to release it on the App Store.

Is there a way to let other people use my Expo App on iPhone without creating a Developer Account? I am looking forward to your advice!  I am on Windows 10 if it matters.

Comment: No, you need a paid developer program membership. Even if you want to distribute builds directly to people you know, you need to register their device IDs in the apple developer portal. A paid program member can register up to 100 devices. A free developer member can only register a single device and builds are only valid for 7 days. Paid membership also gives access to Testflight where you can distribute pre release builds that are valid for 90 days to large numbers of people. You will also need access to a Mac to build and iOS release